# Self attribute not working python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, compiler-errors, pygame

I am trying to create a simple object-oriented pong game. I have a `Player` object and one method (`create_paddle`). When I create an instance of `Player` and call the `create_paddle` method it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Documents\python_programs\pong.py", line 30, in   <module>
    player1.create_paddle(30, 180, 15, 120)
TypeError: create_paddle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'h'
```

Program:

```
class Player:

    def create_paddle(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, white, (x, y, w, h))

player1 = Player
player1.create_paddle(30, 180, 15, 120)
```

I have looked up the error and no other posts helped. 
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks, JC

Comment: `player1 = Player()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing parentheses when creating the object:

```
player1 = Player()
```

Which means you're just assigning player1 to Player and trying to call your method like a static method....so self isn't getting passed for you.

```
player1.create_paddle(player1, 30, 180, 15, 120)
```

That is what python does for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Wow! Such a stupid mistake I had been looking at for half an hour. Thanks!

Comment: @J-Carder you should consider accepting my answer and any stackoverflow answer on your questions if it works for you and solves your problem, so stackoverflow can remove it from the 'unanswered' pages. and as a way to say thank you...apart from thank you which you already said :)